# IntegrityError at /adduser (1048, "Column 'username' cannot be null")

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views

I am trying to create a simple user registration following the CRUD procedure but i encounter the following problem whenever i try to key in a user`s details.

Here is my adduser function.

```
def adduser(request):
    username = request.POST.get('firstname');
    email = request.POST.get('email');
    password = request.POST.get('password');
    
    newuser = User(username=username,  email=email, password=password);
    
    newuser.save();
    
    return render(request, 'vinstarapp/index.html', {})
```

I tried using first_name, last_name but had a type error at adduser/
Changed it to username and now the integrity error.

Comment: Can you share the full error traceback by editing the question?

Comment: Also I think you mean `request.POST.get('username');` instead of `request.POST.get('firstname');` is it?

Comment: It is preferable to use `User.objects.create_user()`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/

Answer (score 0):

```
    username = request.POST.get('firstname');
```

The OP makes it pretty clear that we computed a `None` value here
and assigned it to the username.

I don't know why that happened.
Maybe the web client explicitly supplied such a value in the POST data?
Maybe there's a `first_name` typo?
Maybe the naming inconsistency between username / firstname has come back to bite us?

In any event, supply a default value so the INSERT can succeed:

```
    username = request.POST.get('firstname', 'default_user')
```

---

Also, how did all those extra `;` semicolons sneak in there?
This source code would benefit from
[black](https://pypi.org/project/black)
making a cleanup pass over it.